# Not able to get output in hdfs directory using hdfs as sink in flume

Tags: flume

I am trying to give normal text file to flume as source and sink is hdfs ,the source ,channel and sink are showing registered and started but nothing is comming in output directory of hdfs.M new to flume can anyone help me through this???????

Comment: Can you show the content of flume config which you use?

Answer (score 0):

Conf for flume .conf file are

```
agent12.sources = source1
agent12.channels = channel1
agent12.sinks = HDFS

agent12.sources.source1.type = exec
agent12.sources.source1.command = tail -F /usr/sap/sample.txt


agent12.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent12.sinks.HDFS.channels = channel1


agent12.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs

agent12.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path= hdfs://172.18.36.248:50070:user/root/xz


agent12.channels.channel1.type =memory
agent12.channels.channel1.capacity = 1000
```

agent started using

```
/usr/bin/flume-ng agent -n agent12 -c usr/lib//flume-ng/conf/sample.conf -f /usr/lib/flume-ng/conf/flume-conf.properties.template
```